# Meteor/MongoDB Conversation Schema

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm having trouble setting up a proper conversation schema that stores read/unread flags of conversations and/or messages. I want the current logged in user to be able to see how many conversations have new messages in them. Currently, my schema (using imple-schema) looks a little like this:

```
Schema = {};

Schema.ConversationMessageRead = new SimpleSchema(
    {
        "userId": {
            type: String
        },
        "createdAt": {
            type: Date
        }
    }
);

Schema.ConversationMessage = new SimpleSchema(
    {
        "userId": {
            type: String
        },
        "message": {
            type: String,
            optional: true
        },
        "read": {
            type: [Schema.ConversationMessageRead],
            optional: true
        },
        "createdAt": {
            type: Date
        }
    }
);

Schema.Conversation = new SimpleSchema(
    {
        "participants": {
            type: [String],
            optional: false
        },
        "messages": {
            type: [Schema.ConversationMessage],
            optional: true
        },
        "deleted": {
            type: Boolean,
            optional: false,
            defaultValue: false
        },
        "createdAt": {
            type: Date
        }
    }
);

Conversations = new Mongo.Collection("conversations");
Conversations.attachSchema(Schema.Conversation);
```

My thought behind this was to update all message subdocuments `read` property with the current users ID when they open up a conversation. I then quickly found out that you can't [update multiple subdocuments](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) right now.

I'm open to changing the way the conversation system is being managed if someone has an idea on a proper way to achieve this. Another thing to keep in mind is I'd like to keep it reactive, meaning I have to query this collection without using aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to have an event log collection:

```
Schema.EventLog = new SimpleSchema({
  userId: { type: String },
  conversationMessageId: { type: String },
  createdAt: { type: Date }
});
```

Documents in this collection would never be modified (insert, then read-only) which is fast.

Although this does beg the question, if you're going to set all `conversationMessages` as read at once then why not just save the last datetime that a user read a conversation and then you can just see if any messages in that conversation are newer than the last read date? Much less data to accomplish the same end.

Comment: Actually, I originally built the system the way you mentioned in the last paragraph. I was having difficulty querying the data though. I may revisit it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is not a multiple update but rather a single addition to a subdocument array every time the user views a post?  I think this command will achieve the desired result:

```
Conversations.update(
    { _id: CONVERSATION_ID }, 
    { 
        $push: { 
            'messages.read': NEW_CONVERSATION_MESSAGE_READ_OBJECT }
    }
)
```